# Last Update for old ionic 3 App with angular 5

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've an old ionic 3 project, which I want to update a last time to make some changes to prepare the users and the data for the big update when going to ionic 7 some day.
I've cloned my repository and with `npm i` I'm getting:

```
npm WARN deprecated node-fetch-npm@2.0.4: This module is not used anymore, npm uses minipass-fetch for its fetch implementation now
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@5.0.3.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
```

In the angular/cli versions I only found 1.x and then 6.x. Is there no old 5.x anymore?
Is there a way for my last update? In August 2023 I've done the last update, which was no problem at all.